# Where to initialize a static variable in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, static

I'm using a static variable in a class but the problem is that it needs another value from another class for it's initial value(See the code snippet). I thought initializing it in Start function. But (correct me if I'm wrong) that means it will be reinitialized for every instance of the object which is something redundant since I want this variable to be initialized for just once at the creation of very first Unit which has UnitManager on.

So my question is at what place would be considered as a good practice to initialize this variable?

Thanks!

Code:

```
public class UnitManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Distance in terms of Unity Unity from the target position to stop for units
    static float distanceToStop;
    private void Start()
    {
        if (WorldCoordController.OneUnityMeterToRealWorld < 10)
        {
            distanceToStop = 1 / WorldCoordController.OneUnityMeterToRealWorld;
        }

        else
        {
            distanceToStop = 0.1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialize `WorldCoordController.OneUnityMeterToRealWorld` in `Awake()`, awake is called before start, if this does not fit your needs you can set up a script execution order: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I also want to initialize distanceToStop value only for once.

Comment: Then put it inside a static constructor, you could still oveerwrite the value after that so you should mark it as readonly too

Comment: This class is derived from MonoBehaviour and It's not recomended to have constructors inside a MonoBehaviour derived class if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It's not recommended indeed, but there are some cases when it can be good, but why script executin order is not satisfying for you in the first place?

Comment: Then in your Awakes you can put up initialization restrictions

Comment: Script executin order is not the problem for me. I was searching for "the best" way of initializating my static variable (assuming that there exists a best way). But I'll go with initialization restriction method I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class UnitManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Distance in terms of Unity Unity from the target position to stop for units
    static float distanceToStop;
    static bool distanceSet = false;
    private void Start()
    {
        // If the distance is not set
        if(!this.distanceSet)
        {
            if (WorldCoordController.OneUnityMeterToRealWorld < 10)
            {
                distanceToStop = 1 / WorldCoordController.OneUnityMeterToRealWorld;
            } else {
                distanceToStop = 0.1f;
            }

            this.distanceSet = true;
        }
    }
```

The "distanceSet" bool will be shared between the instances so you will only set the distance on the first one :D

Comment: Thanks for reply! I also used the same way but I was searching for a more elegant way. :D But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider calling UnitManager with an Init(); with the WorldCoordController value it needs.

Comment: WorldCoordController doesn't know when and how UnitManager class is initialized.

Comment: That doesn't take away much from my answer. You should still avoid Unity's basic start and awake functions as much as possible. For getting the worldcontroller you could create a static instance of it, which you can get at anytime as @S.Fragkos describes below.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class that will have a static reference to its self and be initialized only once (the first time it gets called).
Example:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    //Static Functionality
    private static ExampleClass _inst;
    public static ExampleClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_inst is null)
            {
                _inst = new ExampleClass();
                _inst.Init();
            }
            return _inst;
        }

    }


    //Class Values
    public static int MyValue;

    public int Value1;

    //private Constructor 
    private ExampleClass()
    {

    }


    //initialize values here
    private void Init()
    {

    }

}
```

And then you can access the values like this:

```
//This will return the Value1 int
ExampleClass.Instance.Value1
```

or

```
//This will return the static MyValue int
ExampleClass.MyValue
```

From what you are asking, you can use only the Value1 from the above example and have it initialized only once in the init. If you want the value to be accessible only for read you can set it as property with "private set" operator.

The advantage of this is you dont need Start or Monobehaviour so it can work anywhere without having it in gameobjects.

Hope this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: I can't quiet understand your solution. This UnitManager class exists on many different objects. (I realized know It's not named correctly though) And I need to derive from MonoBehaviour since It uses many Unity functionalities.

Comment: @AliİhsanElmas What I'm describing is a singleton design pattern (you can find plenty information about it in the internet). About your MonoBehaviour inheritance, if you need Start, Awake, Update etc... then you cant use this I think, but you can use the UnityEngine reference along with what comes with it, (references, functions, everything).